# What are the benefits of using Artifactory as a binary repository manager for hosting my multi-language app code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, binary, storage, artifactory

I am interested in working with JFrog's Artifactory which will be hosted via AWS for a new project of mine and was hoping to get assistance understanding what they mean by being a "binary repository manager?" I plan on using the service to host an app containing code with a multitude of languages, including Python, C, C#, JavaScript.

I assume what they mean by this is that the files are broken down to bits in order to maximize efficiency. From a technical perspective is this a correct assumption, and what might the benefits of storing the source code this way be?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, so comment not answer. Artifactory came out of the Java ecosystem, where it was used to store the "binary artifacts" (JAR files) that were produced from the Java build process. This is in contrast to the "source repository" that was used as the input to the build process. Over time, Artifactory (and competitors) added support for artifacts from different build processes, so things like Python Wheels or Docker Images. And while a Python Wheel contains source code, Artifactory is _not_ intended to replace a source repository like GitHub.

Comment: @kdgregory Got it, thanks for the response. I'm really wondering what people see as the primary benefit to storing their files as binary? Specifically choosing a binary repo vs. source.

Comment: If you have a single, self-contained repository, then you don't need a binary repository: you'll simply deploy from your source tree. But as you add programs, you might find that there are libraries that you want to share between programs. And that's where a binary repository becomes useful, because you build the library, deploy it to the repository, and then the other projects can retrieve the built version.

Comment: For corporate development teams, binary repositories can also be used to ensure the software supply chain. First, because you can restrict the third-party libraries used by your developers. And second (and more important, imo), because you'll have your own copy of a third-party library should the source be unavailable or the developer decide to no longer distribute it.